# vagrant laravel/box does not connect / unpack

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I tried to instal laravel/homestead on Win 8.1

I have Virtualbox 5.0.14 installed.
I also have Vagrant 1.8.1 installed.

I tried using Laravel docs how-to, also I read a couple dozens of tutorials and troubleshooters, including YouTube video tutorials and Stack Overflow posts.

No luck.

Here what I tried:

1. command from Laravel Homestead site:

```
$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead

//I got this error
PS U:\laravel> vagrant box add laravel/homestead
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
```

2. I thought: maybe it is omething with my network, firewall etc, so I tried another approach and downloaded latest virtualbox.box on my local drive u:/laravel

```
curl -O -L  https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.4.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

Then I tried to run homestead from local file:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead ./virtualbox.box

//I also tried: vagrant box add laravel/homestead U:/laravel/virtualbox.box

//I got this error:
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://U:/laravel/virtualbox.box
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

3. Then I tried this:

```
PS U:\laravel> vagrant init laravel/homestead
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
PS U:\laravel> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
```

4. When above did not work, I tried to do the same, but from locally downloaded virtualbox.box:

```
PS U:\laravel> vagrant init laravel/homestead ./virtualbox.box
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
PS U:\laravel> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Unpacking necessary files from: file://U:/laravel/virtualbox.box
    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

I also tried (just to see if anything installs at all):

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
$ vagrant up
```

... no luck.

I made sure I work from within proper directory - at first I tried dir on C: drive (where OS-win81 resides), but I also tried totally different drive U:
Again ... no luck.

I tried Command Prompt, PowerShell, GIT Bash ... just make sure this is not a problem.
I also tried to use them as Administrator. Again, not much of luck.

Oh, and I tried replacing original bsdtar.exe with one from source forge.

I even unpacked virtualbox.box using WinRAR (down to element files) and packed it using ZIP and then tried to add box from local, zipped file.

Again ... no luck.

Anyone came across similar problems and managed to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Well, I think I stick to XAMMP with PHP 7 (especially that I prefer Apache over Nginx). It took me an easy hour to setup and configure XAMMP (incl. self gen. SSL cert and vhosts) and setup and config Laravel 5 / composer / node etc. It would be nice to know thou, why Homestead fails on Win8.1, but that would have to wait for another day.

Answer (score 1):

Well Jeffz, there are a lot of reasons that you were not successful with the installation. I might not be able to go through all of them but I will guide you through the steps which will help in getting Homestead running. Follow the following steps for the offline box:

- After downloading the box from atlas, you will get hc-download file, rename if to virtualbox.box
- Install the box by following command in CMD:

> vagrant box add laravel/homestead file:///Path/to/the/virtualbox.box

Source: https://abbasharoon.me/laravel-homestead-windows-extremely-easy/

Comment: To tell you quite frankly, I tried every tutorial, troubleshooting guide ... anything and everything I found online ... to no avail. I will try your suggestion as well ... just not this week - a grinding wheel is spinning a bit too fast. Thank you thou.

Comment: I will be glad to help on every step :)